# Invalid Field error Contact object

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-object, custom-field

On using update contact I am getting an error:

" Invalid field gender__c for Contact "

Although I do not query such field , or use it in visual force page or even there isnt any such field in contact object as I search . I am not sure where else I should look for the error.

I have been stripping out my code to narrow down the problem .. Here is the current state of my code:

My visualforce :

```
<!-- Profile div -->
 <!-- ============================================================================================== -->
  <div id="profile" class="tab-pane fade in active">
     <div class="container hide_show" id="hide">

        <apex:form styleClass="form-control center" > 
         <apex:pageBlock >
          <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
         <div class="btn btn-success " id="edit">Edit</div>
          </apex:pageBlockButtons>
          <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" title="Personal Details">

              <apex:outputText value="{!contact.firstname}" label="First Name :"/>



          </apex:pageBlockSection>
         </apex:pageBlock>

     </apex:form>    
        </div>   
    <div class="container hide_show" style="display:none" id="show">   
    <apex:form styleClass="form-control center" >   
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!updateContact}"/>
                <apex:commandButton id="edit" value="Cancel" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>

            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" title="Details">
                <apex:inputText value="{!contact.firstname}" label="First Name :"/>

            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
       </apex:form>
</div>   


  </div><!--end profile-->
```

And this is the controller :

```
public without sharing class ContactController_copy{

// error messages for login page ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    private static final String EMAIL_ERROR = 'Please enter a valid Email';
    private static final String ID_ERROR = 'No record found with this email: Contact admin';
    private static final String WRONG_PASS = 'Oops.Password and Email do not match';

// variable -----------------------------------------------

    public Contact contact{get; set;}
    public String emailText{get;set;} 
    public String passwordText{get;set;} 
    public Boolean loggedIn = false;
    public String Id {get; set;}





    public ContactController_copy() {

        if(!loggedIn){
            redirect_login();
        }               
    }

    public PageReference redirect_login(){
       PageReference pg = Page.refugee_main_tfi_back2;
       pg.setRedirect(true);
        return pg;
    }


public PageReference getMyLogin(){
        System.Debug('i am here');
        // verify the email inputs are present and not empty strings
        if(!checkInputValid(emailText, EMAIL_ERROR)) { return null; }

        // now see if you can get the user with this email
        Contact [] lstContacts = [select Id,password__c, firstname from Contact where Email = :emailText ];
        if(!checkContactFound(lstContacts)) { return null; } 

        else if(lstContacts[0].password__c.compareTo(passwordText) != 0){
          ApexPages.addMessage(new Apexpages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.FATAL, WRONG_PASS));
          return null;
        }

             // if validated everything, redirect to detail page for found HBT ID

                contact = lstContacts[0];


             loggedIn = true;
             return Page.refugee_dash_tfi_backup2;



    }

    public PageReference logMeOut(){
        loggedIn = false;
        return Page.refugee_main_tfi_back2;
    }

    public PageReference MyActionMethod()
       {
          if(!loggedIn){
              ApexPages.addMessage(new Apexpages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.FATAL, 'Logged Out'));
              return Page.refugee_main_tfi_back2;
          }

          return null;
       }



    public Pagereference updateContact() {
       try {

            update contact; // this is creating the error message


       } catch (DmlException ce) {
           System.debug('An unexpected error has occurred: ' + ce.getMessage());

       }

       return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a trigger on contact?

Comment: @Eric I see some triggers on contact , but they have been there since months , my update code was working in the morning, and now it somehow doesn't.. I have reversed all the changes I did.

Comment: May be in your team some one has changed the code like create the field for testing add in the code after test remove the field but forget to remove from code. check debug log for line number and complete detail it will help you.

Comment: @swatisaoji Do you install npsp in your org ?

Answer (score 1):

The issue isn't in your code since you're not referencing that field. It's either in a trigger or something like a workflow/process. There shouldn't be a way of any of the latter two having a reference to an invalid field, so I'd suspect a trigger.

Given that you can't save code with a bad field reference, and you can't delete a field that's reference, it sounds like it's a soft reference, i.e. it's being used as part of a dynamic SOQL query or using the SObject accessor methods. I think you're only real option here is to search the whole code base for that field name and see if it does exist somewhere it should't.

Another way to find out where the issue might be would be to run all the test methods and hope they've been written properly.

Comment: thanks for the pointer. I serched the code , i dint find any reference.